# TemplateDoesNotExist at /account/password_reset_confirm/MQ/set-password/ registrationpassword_reset_confirm.html

Tags: python, django

I`m using the Django authentication system to reset the user password. I create an app named account, in which I add the following codes in the urls.py modules:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    path('password_reset/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'),
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

I create all the templated needed in the app`s template/registration repository:
password_reset_form.html, password_reset_done.html, password_reset_confirm.html, password_reset_complete.html,

And I also add the email setting to my project:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '********'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**********'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I run the server, on the password reset page I enter the email that the user is verified, after that, I received the password reset link in my inbox, but When I click it then the TemplateDoesNotExist exception occurs.

Comment: I am not sure. But try renaming template to templates.

Comment: Sorry, I misspell that template, I have 's' in my app`s templates repository.@Biplove Lamichhane

Comment: I delete the path view template, 'template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'),',  then the confirm password link will take me to the Django administration page for Password reset confirmation, sure it work but I don`t want that, which is why I set a password_reset_confirm template.

Comment: I watched Corey Schafer`s video on YouTube of Full-Featured Web App Part 12 - Email and Password Reset   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tyBEsHSv7w&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=12

Comment: show your settings.py **TEMPLATES**

Comment: Thanks, @c.grey. I`ve solved the problem by checking template name and modifying the codes in urls.py of the app

Answer (score 0):

I read the Django Documentation of Using the Django authentication system at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views.
Then I change the template name password_reset_confirm.html to password-reset-confirm.html, and somehow it works!

Answer (score 0):

Is 'registration' the name of the folder where you put all of your templates files? if it is, all of the `as_view()` should have template_name inside them e.g `auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html'), name='password_reset')`